# How to get output of List of workrequest in Workmanager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have following code for workmanager and I want to get output of event workrequest. I tried getWorkInfoByIdLiveData on every workerRequest but some files have no data after compression.

```
for(file in selectedFileList){
      val workerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CompressImageWorker::class.java)
      requestList.add(workerRequest)
     }
     WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(requestList)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to assign a Tag to your work requests and then observe the list of livedata that you receive from [getWorkInfosByTagLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(java.lang.String)).
You can find a sample using Tags in WorkManager's codelab both in [Java](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/index.html) and [Kotlin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager-kt/index.html).

More information can be found on WorkManager's documentation: [Work States and observing work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation).